# Split big file everytime </byebye> occurs

Tags: php, file, split

Below code splits my file every 10 lines, but I want it to split everytime

```
</byebye>
```

occurs. That way, I will get multiple files each containing;

```
<byebye>
*stuff here*
</byebye>
```

Code:

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Split large files into smaller ones
 * @param string $source Source file
 * @param string $targetpath Target directory for saving files
 * @param int $lines Number of lines to split
 * @return void
 */
function split_file($source, $targetpath='files/', $lines=10){
$i=0;
$j=1;
$date = date("m-d-y");
$buffer='';

$handle = @fopen ($source, "r");
while (!feof ($handle)) {
    $buffer .= @fgets($handle, 4096);
    $i++;
    if ($i >= $lines) {
        $fname = $targetpath.".part_".$date.$j.".xml";
        if (!$fhandle = @fopen($fname, 'w')) {
            echo "Cannot open file ($fname)";
            exit;
        }

        if (!@fwrite($fhandle, $buffer)) {
            echo "Cannot write to file ($fname)";
            exit;
        }
        fclose($fhandle);
        $j++;
        $buffer='';
        $i=0;
        $line+=10; // add 10 to $lines after each iteration. Modify this line as required
    }
}
fclose ($handle);
}

split_file('testxml.xml')

?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: use simplexml_load_string() to work with xml

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Any chance you could post a larger sample of your XML or could you confirm that you want to save the content each of BYEBYE element into a separate XML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, this should do it.

```
$content = file_get_contents($source);
$parts = explode('</byebye>', $content);
$parts = array_map('trim', $parts);
```

Then just write the parts to the different files

```
$dateString = date('m-d-y');
foreach ($parts as $index => $part) {
  file_put_contents("{$targetpath}part_{$dateString}{$index}.xml", $part);
}
```

But I assume (without knowing your source), that this will result in *invalid* xml. You should use one of the XML-Parser (SimpleXML, DOM, ..) to handle xml-files.

Sidenote: You use `@` much much too much.

Comment: Wouldn't "explode" cause alot of memory usage? Invalid XML isn't a problem, it's going to be parsed as-if it's html. Anyway, I'll give it a go, thanks.

Comment: Depends on the file size and as long as you don't run into memory issues, you should use the _simplest_ solution. It seems, that you want to run it from command line. There is memory usually not such a big thing.

Comment: Well your method seems to be working fine on my 17megabyte file. Do you think I'd start getting in trouble with a 1GB file on a 512MB-RAM server? For future reference, that is. Thanks for your quick answer!

Comment: well i think in this case this is probably a bad idea... if youre splitting the files up its probably because of size in the first place - or it will be at some point in the future.

Comment: Switch from file_get_contents to use fopen and fread if you are foreseeing size issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about sizes you can switch to a file resource and use fread or fgets to control the amount of memory you are hitting.

```
$f = fopen($source, "r");
$out = '';

while (!feof($f)) 
{
    $line .= fgets($f);

    $arr = explode('</byebye>', $line);
    $out .= $arr[0];

    if (count($arr) == 1)
        continue;  
    else
    {
        // file_put_contents here
        // will need to handle lines with multiple </byebye> entries here, 
        // outputting as necessary

        // replace $out with the final entry of the $arr array onto 
    }

}
```

You can also save more memory by opening up the file for output, and as you parse, pipe the contents to it. When you encounter a  entry you would close the file and open the next one.

Comment: Thanks Bob, this should come in handy when I start hitting bigger files.